# How's the `pallet::extra_constants` different from `pallet::constant`. How to choose?

Tags: pallet

I'm trying to understand the `#[pallet::extra_constants]` and how it's different from `#[pallet::constant]`.

And appropriate scenario for the same.

Answer (score 2):

> https://paritytech.github.io/substrate/master/frame_support/attr.pallet.html

```rust
// pallet_a.rs
#[pallet::config]
pub trait Config: frame_system::Config {
    #[pallet::constant]
    type Foo: Get<u32>;
}


#[pallet::extra_constants]
impl<T: Config> Pallet<T> {
    pub fn bar() -> u32 {
        0
    }
}
```

As you can see, the `constant` can only be defined in the `Config` trait.
You must define a type first and then mark it as constant.

`extra_constants` can be defined without that limitation. But this constants can not be configured in runtime.

```rust
// runtime.rs
// You can not configure the `extra_constants` here.
impl pallet_a::Config for Runtime {
    type Foo = ConstU32<10>;
}
```

Comment: Worth noting the key difference: the `Config` trait is instantiated by the _user_ of the pallet (who implements the `Config` for their runtime) and the `extra_constants` are defined by the _author_ of the pallet - potentially totally independently of the main runtime configuration.